# How to fill parent with EditText in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

Basically, what I want is to have the EditText fill in the rest of the field. Since the first label is a wrap_content and the last item is just an imageview. I am not able to get the EditText to fill in the rest. Originally, I had it in a LinearLayou, but this wasn't working for me either.

Here's the layout so far:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/email_form"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/input_height"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/t_button_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/form_edittext_background"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/input_padding" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/email_lbl"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:maxWidth="150dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/input_label_margin_left"
                    android:text="adsadasdsa asd asdasd asdas  dasd asd asdasda s"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/o_text"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/input_label_font" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/email_txt"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@color/o_form_bg"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:text="aasdsd"
                    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/passwordTxt"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/email_lbl"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/chk_email"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/o_font_input" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/chk_email"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/uplay"
                    android:src="@drawable/i_check2"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                     />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you swapped `toRightOf` and `toLeftOf`

Try this :

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_txt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/o_form_bg"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:text="aasdsd"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/passwordTxt"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chk_email"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/email_lbl"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:textColor="@color/dark"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:textSize="@dimen/o_font_input" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
<EditText
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    ... />
```

Note: fill_parent is deprecated and is a synonym for match_parent so it's not what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Layout_weight attribute.

set `android:layout_weight = "0"` for the other 2 views and `android:layout_weight = "1"` for the editText which should take all space